# Outlook VSTO add-in 80080005 exception while looking up tasks

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a VSTO add-in, that looks up an Outlook task by an EntryID or a Subject, and does some operations on it.

One of the users logged the following error message from it:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Here's the function that finds the Task Item

```
public Outlook.TaskItem FindTask(String EntryID, String Subject)
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.Application OutlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder tasksFolder = null;
        Outlook.Items taskFolderItems = null;
        Outlook.Items filteredtaskFolderItems = null;
        Outlook.TaskItem task = null;


        ns = OutlookApp.Session;
        ns.SendAndReceive(false);
        tasksFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        taskFolderItems = tasksFolder.Items;

        //Try to find the task by entryID
        dynamic OutlookItem = null;
        OutlookItem = ns.GetItemFromID(EntryID);
        if (OutlookItem != null)
        {
            if (OutlookItem is Outlook.TaskItem)
            {
                Outlook.TaskItem foundItem = (Outlook.TaskItem)OutlookItem;
                return foundItem;
            }
        }

        //If not found by EntryID, find it by a Subject
        string subjectmatch = "[Subject] ='" + Subject + "'";
        filteredtaskFolderItems = taskFolderItems.Restrict(subjectmatch);

        for (int i = 1; i <= filteredtaskFolderItems.Count; i++)
        {
            task = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TaskItem)filteredtaskFolderItems[i];
            return task;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've found a couple of explanations for the error log, but none of them really made sense (multiple users accessing the same COM interface, messed up registry etc.)

Any clear signs that maybe the code is wrong, and that's the reason this exception is being generated, or it's Outlooks fault?

I have to mention, that I'm instantiating Outlook from another Office application.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely means your app is running in a security context different from that of Outlook.
Is either app running with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator)?

Also, if this code is in an addin, why are you creating a new instance of the Outlook.Application instead of using the instance passed to your addin?

Comment: Hello Dmitry! Thank you for your reply, and being active on these Outlook issues! The code that I mentioned above runs in an Excel add-in, where I create an Outlook instance, and work from there. The add-in creates a connection between Excel and Outlook, that's why I instantiate a new Outlook object.

Regarding the security context, I am unaware of any information regarding it, I followed MSDN tutorials and articles, and the SDK, to create this. I can't reproduce the issue, but some of my clients can. It looks like Outlook times out whenever he wants, and causes an exception..Any more ideas?

Comment: Also, I would be extremely happy if you could check out this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782786/c-sharp-outlook-vsto-add-in-error-while-trying-to-get-item-in-an-exchange-setup

It's another Outlook mistery, that I'm unable to solve.

Comment: So is either run launched as "run As Administrator"? Does it work if Outlook is **not** running prior to your code instantiating an instance of the Outklook.Applicaiton object?

Comment: I have not know of a requirement, that the add-in has to be running under administrator privileges. Usually I start up the office applications as they are, without the hassle of right-clicking and running as administrator. It works if Outlook is not running, and it even works if it is. I know there is room for improvement here, so if it's already running, I should just get the running instance and not create a new one, but for the sake of simplifying the code example I left it out. And it doesn't seem to have an effect on the reported problem. Worst thing is, that I can't reproduce the same...

Comment: There is no such requirement. But you will run into a problem if the security contexts mismatch.